# Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fn_RegexIsMatch", or the name is ambiguous

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am using this method in my repository class of asp.net MVC 3 application:

```
internal void UpdatePersonEmail(Person person)
{            
    context.Entry(person).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();               
}
```

but I am getting this error:

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or
>   aggregate "dbo.fn_RegexIsMatch", or the name is ambiguous.

on following line:

```
context.Entry(person).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
```

any suggestion how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is not related to your error. It is SQL Server error complaining about some problem in your database. I guess your database table has some trigger, constraint or computed column dependent on SQL function `dbo.fn_RegexIsMatch` which doesn't exist.